# How to set server level custom error text in Websphere application server

Tags: java, websphere, stack-trace, custom-error-pages

There is currently a requirement for us to edit the text delivered error messages that the IBM Websphere throws when it could not access the application, we limited the IP addresses which can access the application.
in case of invalid IP address, Websphere looks for a custom error page which we added in our application but it can't access them so it throws

```
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below
```

also with `500 java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid host header`
and `404 SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404`

I already tried Webcontainer custom property `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.displayTextWhenNoErrorPageDefined` which allows the display of the custom text when there is no error page defined at the application level, but it doesn't work.
and there is `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressHtmlRecursiveErrorOutput` which prevent printing stacktrace, but it's not a solution for me.

I just need to make these errors more human readable with just a simple text. and it needs to be done only in Websphere and not in the application code.

Comment: I had to redirect the page to a 500 error page but it's not pretty. anyway, I'll wait for a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a service request with IBM for this exact issue. I asked them if there is a way to customize the response for SRVE0260E. (that is, something similar to custom property com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound for SRVE0017W)

IBM's response was, "I have discussed your concern with our SME, we don't have any property like that for SRVE0260E."

So, it appears the best we can do at the moment is suppress the stack trace with com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressHtmlRecursiveErrorOutput.